# How to properly inspect SwiftUI View Tree?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, viewbuilder

The problem I'm trying to solve is quite similar to reimplementing a part of `List`.

So for example I have this:

```swift
struct MyList<Content: View>: View {
    
    var content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content
    }
}
```

Here my content can be a `Section`, a `View` or a `TupleView` composed by `Section`s or others `View`s, or even nested `ForEach`s (so others `Section`s).
How can I flatMap the content to a simple array of `Section`s?

Comment: There's been some discussion of this on SO before. I believe the general consensus is that `Content` is opaque and doesn't allow us to inspect the individual components that may or may not make up the view.

Comment: Well... actually in SwiftUI there is no such thing as "view tree" - there is only one "view" (context, layer, whatever...) in which SwiftUI view is rendered in-place (on the fly, once, etc.). So what you named "tree" exists actually only on a stack of rendering, no more. But if you want iterate over provided content, you have to make this content "iteratable" by yourself, because by default it is opaque.